# Convert string DD.MM.YYYY to Date YYYY-MM-DD SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to convert string data from table to data format?
Like 01.12.2000 to 2000-12-01
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSn6d.png)

I really appreciate any help you can provide

```
SELECT
 birthday,
 CAST(birthday AS DATE [DATETIME]) as birthday_date,
 CURRENT_DATETIME() as now

FROM
 `staff`
```

Comment: Try this: `SELECT birthday, FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', birthday)) AS birthday_date, CURRENT_DATETIME() AS now FROM staff`

Comment: Yeah, i can find soulition there

Answer (score -2):

e.g. `SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', '03.03.1990')) AS birthday_date` will do the trick.

Useful links

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time

Comment: you noticed that his date has the format  01.12.2000